# Why is my script hanging?

Tags: ruby

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out why this is hanging. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I've formatted my `||` for the `if` statement:

```
  rods = {
        :rod1 => [3,2,1],
        :rod2 => [],
      :rod3 => []
           }  

init_rod = gets.chomp.to_sym
if ((init_rod != :rod1 || init_rod != :rod2) || init_rod != :rod3)
  print "Type in \"rod1\", \"rod2\", or \"rod3\": "
elsif rods[init_rod].empty?
  print "Rod has no discs. Select another rod other than #{init_rod}: "
else 
  disc = rods[init_rod].pop
end
```

Comment: You probably want a chain `&&` rather than a chain of `||` because if it is not one or not the other or not the other, it must therefore _always_ be true, because by not being the first, it needn't satisfy the second or third.

Comment: `if ((init_rod != :rod1 && init_rod != :rod2) && init_rod != :rod3)`

Comment: Or a more idiomatic Ruby would use an array and `include?` as in `if ![:rod1,:rod2,:rod3].include? init_rod`

Comment: oh, dumb me. makes perfect sense now. the include? way of doing it is so much cleaner. thanks

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I prefer `unless [:rod1,:rod2,:rod3].include? init_rod`

Comment: @pjs In many circumstances so do I, but not often when there are `else` cases involved.  `unless/else` is kind of evil imho.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Or just `!rods.keys.include? init_rod`. Or even better: `!rods.has_key? init_rod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hanging because you have instructed it to wait for entry with `gets`.

Just put a `print` beforehand, or type blindly. It will work.